# Can we use VSTS CAL license to access TFS on premises?

Tags: tfs

We have TFS Server license which got along with MSDN.  But we need to have more CALS as more users need to access our TFS Server.

TFS CAL license cost more, when we look for an alternate we found that VSTS CALS can be used to access TFS On Premises Server.

Could any one can confirm whether it is right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VSTS CAL's include access to TFS.

[Team Foundation Server Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/)

> Buy VSTS for TFS CALs. When you buy VSTS users (starting at $6/month), those same users have a TFS CAL and can connect to any TFS in your organization. If those users also need TFS extensions like Test Manager or Package Management, or if you need additional Private Pipelines for your team, you can purchase these through the Visual Studio Marketplace. All VSTS charges are month-to-month. See detailed instructions.